# JavaScript file could not be load by given path

Tags: javascript

I am trying to include 5 javascript files which I have written to an HTML file. 

  
However, there is an error message that the files are fail to load.

**Source code:**

```
<html class="gr__2k8dc"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Toilet partition tool</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Downloads\3dmodelproject\files\style.css">




  <script src="C:\Users\Downloads\3dmodelproject\files\three.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\Downloads\3dmodelproject\files\STLLoader.js.download"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\Downloads\3dmodelproject\files\OrbitControls.js.download"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\Downloads\3dmodelproject\files\resources.js.download"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\Downloads\3dmodelproject\files\toiletpartition.js.download"></script>



</head>
```

**The error message:**

[image]

Any clue what's wrong with the path format? Thanks!

Comment: I highly advise against using absolute pathing. Make all your paths relative to the HTML file.

Comment: What is the URL in your browser when you open the `.html` file? Also, what's with those `.js.download` files?

Comment: it would be a boon to use a web server instead of a file folder

Comment: @Phil 
The path is as follows in the browser.

file:///C:/Users/Downloads/3dmodelproject/files/Toiletpartitiontool.html

Comment: you're going to want to stand up a server. The browser doesn't perform the same with items served over file:// it really wants http(s)://. here's a simple one, though there are dozens https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned elsewhere, your paths are absolute paths, rather than relative paths. Essentially what this means, is you've hard-coded the locations of your assets (scripts/css/images/etc), making it very difficult to deploy the site, or move the location of your site on your local drive.

In addition, it causes problems with cross origin requests (the actual error you're seeing). Using a relative path resolves that issue, as you're *guaranteed* to be referencing the same origin.

You mentioned in your comment, the html file is: `C:/Users/Downloads/3dmodelproject/files/Toiletpartitiontool.html`

Thus, the relative *location* here is 
`C:/Users/Downloads/3dmodelproject/files`

In order to then reference

`C:\Users\Downloads\3dmodelproject\files\three.js`, you simply need to use `three.js`.

Thus, your page should be:

```
<html class="gr__2k8dc">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <title>Toilet partition tool</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <script src="STLLoader.js.download"></script>
        <script src="OrbitControls.js.download"></script>
        <script src="resources.js.download"></script>
        <script src="toiletpartition.js.download"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Content here -->
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that only IE/Windows is happy with `C:/`

Try changing the drive to a series of `../`

Each one of those will raise the folder level one. Eventually it will get to the root of the drive/domain and then go down the folders to your file. Depending on where you are running the html file will decide how many `../` to add. Linux and Mac don't use windows drive letters so this is also cross OS compatible.

The link would become:
`../../../../Users/Downloads/3dmodelproject/files/STLLoader.js.download`

I'm 90% sure this is the problem you are having

Comment: OP can just use a relative path from their HTML file which is `C:/Users/Downloads/3dmodelproject/files/Toiletpartitiontool.html`, ie `src="STLLoader.js.download"`. There's no need to traverse all the way to the root directory back again

Answer (score -1):

The reason may be your `\`, which the html requires `/`

**But bonus:**

Can you make the scripts to be the relative path to the index.html?

Make the path to be like `<script src="/3dmodelproject/files/three.js"></script>`

Comment: Using an absolute path like `/3dmodelproject/files/three.js` isn't going to work, especially on Windows